# How to change element.getAttribute('value') or the class state in react testing library

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a form page of a website I'm working on.
The issue that when I try to fill a field of the form and press submit in my test case the value attribute of that field remains null, however when I try it manually it works well.

```
    RetriveForm() {
    return this.state.fields.map((value, i) =>
        <FormStyle key={i}>
            <TextStyled> {value}  </TextStyled>
            {this.state.types[i] === "TextArea" ?
                <StyledTextarea value={this.state.Submittion[i] || ''} type="text" name="Fields" placeholder={value} required onChange={(e) => this.handleField(e, i)} data-rows="1" dir="auto" data-testid={`InputField-${i}`} /> :
                <InputStyle value={this.state.Submittion[i] || ''} type="text" name="Fields" placeholder={value} required onChange={(e) => this.handleField(e, i)} data-rows="1" dir="auto" data-testid={`InputField-${i}`} />
            }
        </FormStyle>
    )
}
handleField(event, i) {
    let Submit = [...this.state.Submittion]
    Submit[i] = event.target.value
    this.setState({ Submittion: Submit });
}
```

my test script

```
    it('Web Department Fill Data', async () => {
    await act(async () => {
        await fireEvent.change(DepartmentField, { target: { value: "Web" } });
    });
    const value = DepartmentField.value;
    expect(value).toBe("Web");
    await act(async () => {
        await fireEvent.click(submitButton);
    });

    await waitFor(async () => {
        expect(screen.queryByTestId("Form Content")).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(screen.queryByText("Web Form")).toBeInTheDocument();
        let Fields = [];
        screen.queryAllByRole('textbox').map(element => {
            Fields.push(element);
        });
        await act(async () => {
            await fireEvent.change(Fields[0], { target: { value: "weaam" } });
        });
        expect(Fields[0].getAttribute('value')).toBe("weaam");


        submitApplicationButton = screen.queryByTestId("SubmitApplication");

        await act(async () => {
            await fireEvent.click(submitApplicationButton);
        });

    }).catch((err) => {
        expect(1).toBe(2);
        console.log("Time Out");
    });
});
```

when I try element.value it works but as mentioned element.getAttribute('value') remains null and this causes me error on submitting because what's sent to the mocked api is null not a value

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure yet about the reason but when I changed queryAllByRole('textbox') to queryAllByTestId('InputField') it worked so I suppose the problem because I retrieved the elements as textbox